# Equivalente a in_array() para usar no Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Para saber se uma variável está em um array.

Existe algo que eu possa usar como se fosse in_array do PHP no Javascript?

Exemplo de como seria no PHP:

```
$cores = ['azul', 'verde', 'amarelo'];
$corParaBuscar = 'verde';
$corEncontradaNoArray = in_array($corParaBuscar, $cores);
```

Resultado -> $corEncontradaNoArray -> true

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o método includes do javascript:

```js
let cores = ['azul', 'verde', 'amarelo'];
let corParaBuscar = 'verde';
let corEncontradaNoArray = cores.includes(corParaBuscar);
console.log(corEncontradaNoArray);
```